# Issue with MySQL explain plan, multiple-field indices and OR clause

Tags: mysql, jpa, jpql, explain, sql-execution-plan

I have an explain plan result that I don't understand. I have the following table that hold messages sent from `senders` and to `recipients`.

```
CREATE TABLE `message` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `message_read` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `send_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `version` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `recipient` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `sender` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index4` (`recipient`,`sender`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index5` (`sender`,`recipient`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_a3km2kv42i1xu571ta911f9dc` FOREIGN KEY (`sender`) REFERENCES `member` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_hn9roqyj131hnul5fuwgwlv9e` FOREIGN KEY (`recipient`) REFERENCES `member` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=33 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is my explain plan:

```
explain select *
    from
        message m 
    where
        (
            m.sender = 1
            and m.recipient= 2
        ) 
        or (
            m.recipient = 1 
            and m.sender= 2 
        )
```

Here is the result from my explain plan:

[image]

I am not sure why the `key` field is `null` (the `possible_keys` does mention the indices I want to use).

How can I make sure the `index4` and `index5` indices are used?

**edit 1**:

I have inserted a number of rows into the table. The following explain:

```
explain select *
    from
        message m FORCE INDEX(index4) 
    where
        (
            m.sender = 1
            and m.recipient= 2
        ) 
        or (
            m.sender= 2 
            and m.recipient = 1 
        )
```

now yields the following results:

```
1   SIMPLE  m   range   index4  index4  16      32  Using where
```

Comment: You can only use one index

Comment: @Strawberry. Thanks. Is there a way to rewrite my query in order to use one index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to force the use of an index, you can use FORCE INDEX...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM message FORCE INDEX(index4) 
 WHERE ((recipient = 2 AND sender = 1) OR (recipient=1 AND sender = 2));
```

On a table of 32 rows, this is probably less efficient than a full table scan.

Comment: Oups. I use JPA in order to generate my queries... Any other way to use the index?

Comment: There will be over 100K rows in production... :-)

Comment: I suspect the optimizer will use the index when it thinks it's beneficial to do so.

Comment: Do you mean to say that with more data in the table the explain plan will give a different result and the index will get used?

Comment: Yes. Others will be able to explain the mechanics of it, but such a small table may not use a (non-primary) index at all.